# swift 3 awslambda invoker error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8, aws-lambda

```
let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()
    lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("myfnc", jsonObject: jsonObject)
        .continueWith(block: {(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
            if( task.error != nil) {
                print("Error: \(task.error!)")

                return nil
            }

            if let JSONDictionary = task.result as? NSDictionary {
                print("Result: \(JSONDictionary)")
                print("resultKey: \(JSONDictionary["resultKey"])")
            }
            return nil
        })
```

This is my code. When i run this code. i am getting an error which says, Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'
Anybody know what the error is?

Comment: this is not awss3 transfer manager. this is awslambda. can u suggest me info.plist changes for this one please

Comment: well link is about error and not about subject.Please check answers on link and give a try.I have never worked on it sorry.

Comment: i have tried in that already. But still its showing error